# How can I get double line-numbers per line in reledmac?

Tags: line-numbering, verse, reledmac

Sometimes editors of old texts think that the lines within a stanza are broken in the wrong way. As they can't simply dismiss the old numbering, which has been in use for hundreds of years, they combine the old numbering with the new line breaks, so that lines are called, e.g., 10, 11/12, and 12/13.

Easy example: Let's assume that the estate executor finds the handwritten draft of a famous poem whose breaks are different from what the typesetter did.

```
% -*- mode: latex; TeX-engine: xetex; coding: utf-8; -*-
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{reledmac}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setmainfont{TeXGyrePagellaX}
\setlength{\stanzaindentbase}{1em}
\setstanzaindents{3,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1}
\linenumincrement{1}
\begin{document}
\begin{ledgroup}
  \beginnumbering
  \setline{10}
  \stanza Golden head, black wing &
  Cling, swing, &
  Spring, sing, &
  Swing up into the apple-tree. \&
  \endnumbering
\end{ledgroup}

\medskip % easy: two lines into one
\begin{ledgroup}
  \beginnumbering
  \setline{10}
  \stanza Golden head, black wing &
  \setline[d]{11/12}Cling, swing, Spring, sing, & % or \setdoubleline{12/13}, print line-number 11/12, also in the apparatus
  Swing up into the apple-tree. \&
  \endnumbering
\end{ledgroup}

\medskip % more difficult: new combination
\begin{ledgroup}
  \beginnumbering
  \setline{10}
  \stanza Golden head, black wing, \setline{10/11} Cling & % line-number 10/11
  \setline[d]{11/12} swing, Spring, & % or \setdoubleline{11/12}, print line-number 11/12, also in the apparatus
  \setline[d]{12/13} sing, Swing up into the apple-tree. \& % line-number 12/13, also in the apparatus
\end{ledgroup}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I am afraid there is not yet actual possibility. Reledmac is conceipted for single line number, as all is automatic. Please open a github issue page, maybe I would find a solution, but for now, I don't see.

Comment: I think the solution should to implement a option to tell "from line x to line y, we have double numbering"

Comment: @Maïeul Where and how can I open a github issue page?

Comment: all is explained in the README file and in the handbook abstract… but look at https://github.com/maieul/ledmac/#debug-and-feature-requests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version 2.26.0 of reledmac, just send on CTAN, provide system which allow you to add "annotation" to line number. Suche annotation:

- can be any arbitrary text content, for example the older line number
- is automatically reset at each line
- is added in the margin
- is added in the footnote.

Here a MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia,fontspec}
\usepackage{libertineotf}
\setmainlanguage{latin}
\setotherlanguage{english}

\usepackage[series={A,B},noend,noeledsec,noledgroup]{reledmac}
\sethangingsymbol{[\,}
\firstlinenum{1}
\linenumincrement{1}
\setcounter{stanzaindentsrepetition}{0}
\setstanzaindents{8,0,0}
\setcounter{stanzaindentsrepetition}{1}

\begin{document}
\begin{english}
\date{}

\title{Stanza with double line numbering}
\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
This file provides an example of typesetting verse with reledmac using a double line numbering system. 

The new edition adds a starting line of verse not present in the previous one, so we need to make an addition within the margin and textsuperscript the numbering from the older edition. In the centre, we split what was in the first edition one line of verse into two.



To mark the old numbering, we use \verb+\linenumannotation+. For maximum clarity, all line numbers are shown thanks to the settings of \verb+\firstlinenum+ and \verb+\linenumincrement+ in the preamble.

\end{abstract}
\end{english}

\beginnumbering

\stanza
\edlabel{begin:1}\edtext{Lorem}{\lemma{Lorem\ldots nisis}\xxref{begin:1}{end:1}\Afootnote{A note on four lines of verse, the first of which was missing in the first edition}} ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,&
\linenumannotation{1}sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore&
\linenumannotation{2}magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud&
\linenumannotation{3}exercitation ullamco laboris nisi\edlabel{end:1}&
\linenumannotation{4}\edtext{ut aliquip}{\Afootnote{ut aliliquip}} consequat ut aliquip consequat irure dolor in reprehenderit irure dolor in reprehenderit&
\linenumannotation{5}\edtext{Duis aute}{\Bfootnote{Some comments}} irure dolor in reprehenderit&
\linenumannotation{6}\edlabel{begin:2}\edtext{in}{\xxref{begin:2}{end:2}\lemma{in\ldots deserunt}\Afootnote{Theses two lines of verse were one single line in the first edition}} voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu ur. Excepteur sint occaecat&
\linenumannotation{6}cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt\edlabel{end:2}&
\linenumannotation{7}\edlabel{begin:3}\edtext{Duis}{\xxref{begin:3}{end:3}\lemma{Duis\ldots occaecat}\Afootnote{Another note on two verses}} aute irure dolor in reprehenderit&
\linenumannotation{8}in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla&
\linenumannotation{9}pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat\edlabel{end:3}\&
\endnumbering

\end{document}
```